# How can I get my own cursor coordinates in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, firebug, coordinates, mouse-coordinates

I'm currently designing a website and just realized it would help me a lot if I would know my own cursor coordinates.

I mostly use Firefox for previewing the new page. So an add-on for Firefox would be great. I checked out Firebug, but didn't find the feature there.

Does anyone know how to show the current cursor coordinates in Firefox?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try [WebDeveloper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60). In Miscellaneous > Display Ruler. Wherever you click/click+drag you get all the coordinates.